# How to promote robot_state_publisher rate?

Tags: ros, rviz, transform, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use tf broadcaster to move arms in rviz, but the rate of robot_state_publisher is 10Hz, which cause lag in simulation. I want to know how to fix that.
I use `rosrun tf view_frames` to check the rate.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295743/how-to-promote-robot_state_publisher-rate?/) by [littleghost](https://answers.ros.org/users/33922/littleghost/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to add `<param name="rate" value="1000"/>`  in my launch file and it seems better now.

The robot_state_publisher rate becomes nearly 50Hz.

---

Originally posted by [littleghost](https://answers.ros.org/users/33922/littleghost/) with karma: 26 on 2018-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should not use the `robot_state_publisher` to drive something. As the name suggests, this publishes the state of the robot, (quote)

> `robot_state_publisher` uses the URDF
> specified by the parameter
> `robot_description` and the joint
> positions from the topic `joint_states`
> to calculate the forward kinematics of
> the robot and publish the results via
> `tf`.

To drive the robot arm you need to use a controller. The arms joints send their state then to the `robot_state_publisher` which again translates that to `tf`.

There is, however, a parameter `publish_frequency` that should let you specify the frequency of [the `robot_state_publisher`](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher). Default is 50Hz.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-06-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [littleghost](https://answers.ros.org/users/33922/littleghost/) on 2018-06-29**:
I run the "rosrun tf view_frames" and find that the robot _state_publisher rate is only 10Hz.

**Comment by [suomynona](https://answers.ros.org/users/75693/suomynona/) on 2021-06-24**:
Did anybody find the solution to this problem. I need faster than 50hz but no matter what I do it stays at max 50hz.